# extjs layout fit property what is the name of this property while writing layout as object

Tags: layout, extjs

```
layout:{
        type:'vbox',
        align:'center',
        
    }
```

This code i am using,
Now i want to add this functionality also

```
layout:'fit'
```

But I am not getting any syntax to do so,
I mean what is the name for fit property when writing layout as object.
I am using ExtJs 6.0.2

Comment: Or is there any other way to do so without using layout property

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Both syntaxes should work, the difference is that layout as an object gives you more config options, while layout as string applies default configs.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I want the items to fir the width of parent container, I also want them to align to center and and get arranged in vertical layout. So I want to all those features.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example add some containers with `center` layout into a parent container, this will do as you want: horizontally centered, displayed vertically and every child container will have to width of the parent container. See code below, I added colour so you can see the width of containers:

```
Ext.create({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    xtype: 'container',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'center',
            style: {
                background: 'lightBlue'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                html: '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'center',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                html: '2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            }],
            style: {
                background: 'lightBlue'
            },
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'center',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                html: '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            }],
            style: {
                background: 'lightBlue'
            },
        }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
layout: {
   type: 'fit' 
}
```

Even if you supply it as a string config, once applied the container setLayout will transform it to an object.

```js
    // https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/src/Container.js-3.html#Ext.container.Container-method-setLayout    
    
    setLayout: function(layout) {
        ///...
        if (typeof layout === 'string') {
            layout = {
                type: layout
            };
        }
        ///...
    }
```